# Move a node from a Doubly-linked-list to another doubly-linked-list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly-linked-list called "all_gods" with both Greek and Norse gods.
And I'm trying to remove all Greek gods from "all_gods" and move them to a "greek_gods" list.

I was able to erase them from all_gods but not to insert them in greek_gods.

And I have a couple of questions regarding the code below:

1. is the Destructor for class Link correct?
2. inside the for loop in the main() should I delete the "q" pointer? it gives "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. Without "delete q" I am able to erase all Greek gods from "all_gods".
3. when I try to insert the same "q" into the "greek_gods" I have a weird behavior ("p" doesn't take the next value, after a couple of iterations).

I'm out of ideas of what I can try. Thanks for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct God
{
    God(const string &n, const string &m)
        : name{n}, mythology{m} {}

    string name;
    string mythology;
};

class Link
{
public:
    Link(const string &n, const string &m, Link *p = nullptr, Link *s = nullptr)
        : god{n, m}, prev{p}, succ{s}
    {
    }
    Link *insert(Link *n);       // insert n before this object
    Link *erase();               // remove this object from list
    Link *find(const string &s); // find s in list

    Link *next() const { return succ; }
    Link *previous() const { return prev; }

    ~Link() // destructor
    {
        if (prev)
            delete prev;
        if (succ)
            delete succ;
    }
    God god;

private:
    Link *prev;
    Link *succ;
};

Link *Link::insert(Link *n) // insert n before this object; return n
{
    if (n == nullptr)
        return this;
    if (this == nullptr)
        return n;
    n->succ = this; // this object comes after n
    if (prev)
        prev->succ = n;
    n->prev = prev; // this object’s predecessor becomes n’s predecessor
    prev = n;       // n becomes this object’s predecessor
    cout << "3.insert " << n << ' ' << n->god.name << "\n\n";
    return n; // returns n(the new element) which is before the top node
}
Link *Link::erase() // remove *p from list; return p’s successor
{
    if (this == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (succ)
        succ->prev = prev;
    if (prev)
        prev->succ = succ;
    cout << "2.erased " << this << ' ' << this->god.name << "\n\n";
    return succ;
}
Link *Link::find(const string &s) // find s in list;
{
    Link *p = this; // pointer p is the pointer to the caller of this function
    while (p)
    {
        if (p->god.name == s)
            return p;
        p = p->succ;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
void print_all(Link *p)
{
    while (p)
    {
        cout << ' ' << p << ' ' << p->god.name << ", " << p->god.mythology;
        if (p = p->next()) // moved to the next node
            cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
try
{
    Link *all_gods = new Link{"Four", "Greek"};
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Three", "Greek"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"Two", "Norse"});
    all_gods = all_gods->insert(new Link{"One", "Greek"});
    cout << "all_gods:\n";
    print_all(all_gods);
    cout << "\n\n";
    Link *greek_gods = nullptr;

    for (Link *p = all_gods; p != nullptr; p = p->next())
    {
        if (p->god.mythology == "Greek")
        {
            cout << "1.found " << p << ' ' << p->god.name << '\n';

            Link *q = all_gods->find(p->god.name);
            cout << "q found " << q << ' ' << q->god.name << '\n';
            if (q)
            {
                if (q == all_gods)
                    all_gods = all_gods->next();
                q->erase();
                //greek_gods = greek_gods->insert(q); // insert q in d
            }
            delete q; // gives core dumped - it's deleted at the exit of if() ? no, needs to be deleted at the function's exit
        }
    }
    // delete p; // no need for this because it's decimated by p=p->next() ?

    cout << "all_gods:\n";
    print_all(all_gods);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "greek_gods:\n";
    print_all(greek_gods);
    cout << "\n";

    delete all_gods;
    delete greek_gods;
}
catch (exception &e)
{
    cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
catch (...)
{
    cerr << "exception\n";
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: This program is simple enough that you can walk through it with a debugger, or even simulate the steps with pen and paper. Did you notice that `p` and `q` point to the exact same object? That makes accessing `p` after calling `delete q` an illegal memory access.

Comment: Thanks! No, I didn't notice... so I need to rethink this...

Comment: Regardless, you should not be deleting p or q before the end of the program.